# How to include loadpath/dependency in rakefile

Tags: ruby, path, include, directory, rakefile

I have installed, Ruby 1.8.7, ci_reporter 1.8.4, test unit 2.5.4, rake 10.0.3.

My testA.rb :

```
require 'includeA.rb'
require 'includeB.rb'
require 'includeC.rb'
require 'includeD.rb'

Begin of the code...
... End of the code
```

Usually I execute a test with the following cmd :

```
ruby -I E:/pathToIncludeA/includeA.rb -I E:/pathToIncludeB/includeB.rb -I E:/pathToIncludeC/includeC.rb -I E:/pathToIncludeD/includeD.rb E:/pathToTestA.rb/testA.rb
```

And all works fine.

But now I am using rake, and i am trying to include directory in the same way.

Here my rakefile :

```
require 'rake/testtask'
require 'rubygems'
gem 'ci_reporter'
gem 'test-unit' 
require 'test/unit' 
require 'ci/reporter/rake/test_unit'  

task :default => [:test]

task :test do
  ruby '-I E:/pathToIncludeA/includeA.rb', '-I E:/pathToIncludeB/includeB.rb, '-I E:/pathToIncludeC/includeC.rb', '-I E:/pathToIncludeD/includeD.rb', E:/pathToTestA.rb/testA.rb
end
```

But when i execute the following cmd :

```
rake test
```

I've got the following error :

```
E:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in 'gem_original_require': no such file to load -- includeA.rb (load error)
from E:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in 'require'
from E:/pathToTestA/testA.rb/

rake aborted!
command failed with status (1): [E:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe -I pathToIncludeA/...]
Tasks: TOP => default => test
```

What I did wrong? Could someone help me?

Comment: What happens when you do this: `sh "ruby -I E:/pathToIncludeA/...` instead of `ruby '-I E:/...`?

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, add your answer, i will give you reputation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
task :test do
  sh "ruby -I E:/pathToIncludeA/includeA.rb -I E:/pathToIncludeB/includeB.rb -I E:/pathToIncludeC/includeC.rb -I E:/pathToIncludeD/includeD.rb E:/pathToTestA.rb/testA.rb"
end
```

or, if you need/like to use the `ruby` method inside the task, change your `testA.rb` to load the paths to the `include(A|B|C|D).rb` and then:

```
task :test do
  # assuming the Rakefile and the testA.rb are in the same folder.
  ruby "testA.rb"
end
```

If your test suite consists of multiple test files like `testA.rb`, `testB.rb` etc, then the `Rake::TestTask` class may make it much easier. Check how the Sinatra project uses it to get an idea: [Sinatra/Rakefile](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/Rakefile) ; [`Rake::TestTask` Documentation](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/TestTask.html)